# The code keeps on trowing an error ```The command help is already an existing command or alias``` Why is this so and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, discord.py

Im working on a discord bot in python but as soon as I run the code it shows an error `The command help is already an existing command or alias.` and it isn't anywhere else in the code.

Here is the code

```
async def help(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title='Help', description='Use s!help <command> for more info on it')
  embed.add_field(name="Moderation", value="Kick, Ban, Mute, Purge/Clean")
  embed.add_field(name="Roleplay", value="Hug, Kiss, Slap, Shoot, Punch, lick, poke, cookies")
  embed.add_field(name="Games", value='Dice, Slots,')
  embed.add_field(name="Extras", value='Weather, Ping')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `help` command already exists so you need to [remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=remove#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command) the default one to overwrite it:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix')
bot.remove_command('help')

#Your code

bot.run(token)
```